# How to find all substring instances?

Tags: vb.net, indexof

I have a program which will locate a substring by index.  For instance, searching for "no" in "Yes no yes no" would return **4**, the character index of the first "no".

I would like it to identify multiple occurrences.  For instance, the above example would return both **4** and **11** (index of the other occurrence).

Comment: Clarified wording and example.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf has a set of overloads that can be used for this.

```
    Dim str = "Yes No Yes No"
    str.IndexOf("No", 6)
```

This starts searching from character 6. However I'd be tempted to use a regular expression instead.

```
    Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("No")
    For Each match As RegularExpressions.Match In regex.Matches(str)
        Console.WriteLine("Match found @ {0}", match.Index)
    Next
```

This will give you much more control of the matching if you need to extend your rules further and IMO provides a clearer interface.

Comment: Wow thanks alot. I will need to do some research into Regular Expressions as I have not used this before. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend having a bit of a read of http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but also have a play with http://regexr.com/ to see them live in action.